# How to add a user to Telegram Group using Wtelegramclient

Tags: c#, telegram, wtelegramclient

How can i add user to telegram group by username. I have try using this method

```
await TelegramClient.Channels_InviteToChannel(target, inputUsers.ToArray());
```

The code didn't add the member to the group and there was no error or exception

Answer (score 1):

No error or exception?

Maybe inputUsers array was empty, or the users were already in the group/channel.

[Here are examples](https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md#add-members) on how to add/invite/remove members in a chat